# No carga la imagen con Picasso en mi RecyclerView

Tags: android

Estoy intentando cargar una imagen con Picasso en el metodo onBindViewHolder(), pero no la carga. Todo funciona salvo eso.

```
package com.example.oftecnica2.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class Adaptador extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.NuevoViewHolder> {
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 ArrayList<Comunicado>comunicados;
Context context;


public Adaptador(Context context,ArrayList<Comunicado> comunicados) {
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.comunicados = comunicados;
    this.context=context;
    System.out.println("AQUIIIIII");
    System.out.println(comunicados.get(0).toString());
}

@Override
public NuevoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_anime,null);
    return new NuevoViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NuevoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    System.out.println("POSICION:         "+position);
    Comunicado comunicado=comunicados.get(2);
    System.out.println("COMUNICADO "+comunicado.toString());
    holder.titulo.setText(comunicado.getTitulo());
    holder.subtitulo.setText(comunicado.getSubtitulo());
    Picasso.with(context).load(comunicado.getEnlace()).into(holder.imagen);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return comunicados.size();
}









public static class NuevoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView subtitulo;
    ImageView imagen;

    public NuevoViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titulo=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        subtitulo=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
        imagen=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);


    }


}
}
```

Se os ocurre que puede suceder? el enlace que recoge encomunicado.getEnlace es correcto, es una foto cualquiera de internet.

Comment: Primeramente, aseguras que tienes el url correcto en : comunicado.getEnlace() ???

Answer (score 1):

Asegura tener una url de imagen por medio de `comunicado.getEnlace()` lo cual pudiera ser una causa, ya que no tiene una url de imagen a cargar

Si tiene imagen entonces agrega una medida, por ejemplo:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(comunicado.getEnlace()).resize(120, 120).into(holder.imagen);
```

Es correcto lo que realizas, agregar la imagen en `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar. He probado a hacerlo con un R.drawable de mi carpeta drawable y lo hace sin problemas...Pero he comprobado que si que muestra un enlace con un sout, y he abierto el enlace y muestra la imagen correctamente en el pc...que puede ser? :S

Comment: Aunque quizá sea algo obvio... La URL de que obtienes en getEnlace es válida? En la mayoría de los navegadores no pasa nada si la URL la muestras sin el http:// pero en Android necesitas añadirlo. Te comento esto porque si dices que con un fichero local te funciona, creo que el problema lo tienes ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Haber yo he implemento, la carga de imágenes con la librería Picasso  de la siguiente manera.

```
public class Adaptador extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.NuevoViewHolder> {
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 ArrayList<Comunicado>comunicados;
 Context context;


public Adaptador(Context context,ArrayList<Comunicado> comunicados) {
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.comunicados = comunicados;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public NuevoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_anime,null);
    return new NuevoViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NuevoViewHolder holder, int position) {
    System.out.println("POSICION:         "+position);

    Comunicado comunicado=comunicados.get(position);
    String urlImagen = comunicado.getEnlace();


    //Condiciono para ver si el resultado es nulo o vació
    if(urlImagen == null || urlImagen.isEmpty()){
    //Acá no uso la librería ya que la imagen que muestro no es pesada
    holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_150dp); //reemplaza la imagen

    }else{
         //Pero si me devuelve una url uso la librería picasso
         Picasso.with(context)
         .load(comunicado.getEnlace())
         .error(R.drawable.ic_image_150dp) //en caso que la url no sea válida muestro otra imagen
         .into(holder.imagen);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return comunicados.size();
}


public static class NuevoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imagen;

    public NuevoViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        imagen=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);


    }


}

}
```

> Espero que te sirva.